# Time and again i get LoadOperation failed

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I don't know why but sometimes the loadoperation succeeds and sometimes it doesn't. Is it because many (6-7) requests are made at same time? All `get` queries fail once in a while. This is one of the errors :-

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.2; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Wed, 16 Mar 2011 03:22:10 UTC


Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException: Load operation failed for query 'GetSiteTerms'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.WebDomainClient`1.EndQueryCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainClient.EndQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.LoadOperation.Complete(Exception error)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.CompleteLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainContext.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<Load>b__17(Object )     

Line: 76
Char: 13
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:9090/Default.aspx
```

Is Ria services unstable or do i need to make some changes in settings of Sql server?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Not found" exception wins second place in unhelpfulness after "General Protection Fault". It could be a number of problems all getting stashed behind that impenetrable "Not found" fortress.

It happens most often because a WCF service call returned an HTTP result 4xx or 5xx. Then, the exception generated by Silverlight does not help in the slightest to debug the problem. But you don't need Silverlight here to help - the problem is server-side after all. If you fire up Fiddler, you'll be able to see the traffic between the Silverlight client and the server. There, you'll also be able to see the exact server response with the exact exception message and stack trace.

Try using the tips in ["How to Permanently Banish Silverlight’s “Not Found” Error for WCF Service Calls"](http://www.benday.com/2010/08/16/how-to-permanently-banish-silverlights-not-found-error-for-wcf-service-calls/) to make the Silverlight errors more palatable.

Comment: It was some memory issue.Checked with Fiddler. I have old laptop with just 2 GB of memory and Visual Studio 2010, Expression Blend and Sql Server everything was running. Because the performance was extremely poor i had turned off Virtual Memory so that data doesn't get written to hard disk but my RAM was near about full so i was getting this error. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @stefan that URL is not found

Comment: Fixed URL, added Fiddler tip.

Answer (score 2):

I was fighting with this error for 2 days and figured out whats the issue is....
By default when you try to load the datasource it can handle only 64K data....when you get not found which means the size is greater than 64k......try replicating the table, bring down the number of rows to 10-15(just testing) and try execute the app it will work fine......